# FFMPEG transcription from .webm to HNxHD

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion

I'm a n00bie with video production.

I installed ffmpeg. It's recognized.

So I tried my first conversion.

> ffmpeg -i earth.webm earth.DNxHD

and, then, after searching:

> ffmpeg -i earth.webm -f DNxHD earth.DNxHD

In both cases I get the following error:

> Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder
> for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate,
> rate, width or height
>
> Conversion failed!

What I gather from that is that the default settings did not work and ffmeg wants me to include those values.

And that's the problem. What values should be selected for these unknown files? (I grabbed them from the web - they're copyright free - and want to use them in Da Vinci Resolve (hence the need for DNxHD)

Included is the error msg

```
C:\Users\GLM\Downloads\test>ffmpeg -i earth.webm -f DNxHD earth.DNxHD
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Earth.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.8.100
  Duration: 00:00:45.55, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 358 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 426x240, SAR 255:254 DAR 3621:2032, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
File 'earth.DNxHD' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp8 (native) -> dnxhd (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] video parameters incompatible with DNxHD. Valid DNxHD profiles:
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 175Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 185Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 365Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 440Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 115Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 120Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 145Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 240Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 290Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 175Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 185Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 220Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 365Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 440Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 185Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 220Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 120Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 145Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 185Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 220Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 120Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 145Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 90Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 180Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 220Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 90Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 110Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 180Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 220Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 60Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 75Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 120Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 145Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 36Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 45Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 75Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 90Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 350Mbps; pixel format: yuv444p10, gbrp10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 390Mbps; pixel format: yuv444p10, gbrp10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 440Mbps; pixel format: yuv444p10, gbrp10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 730Mbps; pixel format: yuv444p10, gbrp10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 880Mbps; pixel format: yuv444p10, gbrp10
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 960x720p; bitrate: 42Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 960x720p; bitrate: 60Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 960x720p; bitrate: 75Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 960x720p; bitrate: 115Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1440x1080p; bitrate: 63Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1440x1080p; bitrate: 84Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1440x1080p; bitrate: 100Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1440x1080p; bitrate: 110Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 80Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 90Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 100Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fc7800] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 110Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p
[dnxhd @ 000001d544fd9800] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNxHD codec has multiple profiles, and the `DNxHD` profile supports only a limited set of parameters. The `DNxHR` profiles does not have these restrictions.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i earth.webm -profile:v dnxhr_hq -f DNxHD earth.DNxHD
```

This will not keep the audio. If you need that, use

```
ffmpeg -i earth.webm -c:v dnxhd -profile:v dnxhr_hq earth.mov
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out tonight, when I get home.

Comment: Thanks. It worked great. Da Vinci isn't importing these files. But that's yet another thing I have to research.